# Use numpy.vectorize on array of arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization, array-broadcasting

How do I apply numpy.vectorize in order to have it act on an array of arrays where each array is an input to the function?
For instance underneath, I am looking for the returns values to be the list [4,90]:

```
import numpy as np
import operator
import functools

vidx = np.vectorize(operator.index)
functools.partial(vidx,0)([[4,3,2],[90,7,6]])

vidx = np.vectorize(functools.partial(operator.index,0))
vidx([[4,3,2],[90,7,6]])
```

None of these set ups seem to interpret the intention correctly. I know you can easily do this with a list comprehension, just looking to expand the idea to custom functions of this type.

Comment: Why overcomplicating? Just `np.array([[4,3,2],[90,7,6]])[:, 0]` where `0` is your index

Comment: I always find `np.vectorize` confusing, it doesn't provide any performance compared to Python native for loop while makes the code harder to understand.

Comment: The code that you show **does not use** arrays; it uses native Python **lists**. It is important to make this distinction in order to understand the proper use of Numpy.

Comment: `np.vectize` iterates on scalar elements of an array, not rows. `index` is a list method, not for array or scalar.

Comment: your aument makes a 2d array, not an array of arrays

Answer (score 0):

Try to define a first element via function, create a 2D array and apply the function to each sub-array along the first axis. Something like that:

```
import numpy as np

def first_element(arr):
    return arr[0]

arr = np.array([[4, 3, 2], [90, 7, 6]])
result = np.zeros(arr.shape[0], dtype=int)

for i in range(arr.shape[0]):
    result[i] = first_element(arr[i])

print(result)
```

Output: [4 90]

Comment: thanks, but I am looking to use np.vectorize to apply index like functions to arrays of arrays. To simply get the result, @RomanPerekhrest 's answer is the best.